# at login on RHEL switch shell to bash

Tags: bash, shell, rhel, login

### **Context:**

We are running a system which has our Linux & Unix Boxes authenticate against AD and because we have numerous different versions of Unix/Linux, we have to default to /bin/sh to make sure that the logins always work no matter the Server. I am looking to setup a .profile on RHEL to check to see what shell is set to at login and if its not bash, to switch to bash. I am not having any luck google searching for a method to do this and my shell scripting is on the weaker side.

### **Question:**

How does one check for shell and switch at login without the control of the passwd file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested. Edit your ~/.profile ...

```
if [ -x /bin/bash ]; then
  exec bash
fi
```

Comment: This does work, as long as there is no recursion happening because of login scripts but I found out its a moot point because the server has /bin/sh -> /bin/bash

Comment: Bash, when invoked as /bin/sh, tries to mimic sh, though.  There's a difference in how it will execute scripts. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like `which bash >/dev/null && exec bash`?
Or is the output of `getent passwd` of any use to you?